# What word could describe a person with integrity or the difference between a person with integrity and one without?

Tags: characters, description

I am trying to get the perfect word to separate those having integrity and those who lack it. I am trying to describe someone who accepts full ownership for their choices even the more regrettable ones

Answer (score 1):

### Quick List:

Here's just a quick list, google any of these and you'll get more.

- Principled
- honest
- upstanding
- upright
- just
- true
- ethical
- moral
- honorable
- virtuous
- trustworthy
- incorruptible
- noble
- decent

Comment: The original term "integrity" — it appears to me — remains a very strong contender to express the intended semantics. In support of this, I point out that most of these examples — in one way or another — do not entirely overlap / cover the meaning. Accordingly, I seem to conclude, however clumsy "having integrity" or "exhibiting integrity" may come across, it may remain the best choice in contexts where conveying the original semantics is paramount. Feel free to update my views on this by bringing further candidate synonyms.

Comment: @Levente I agree, but assumed in the question that integrity didn't quite fit their exact needs, and the wanted something close but not identical. This is hardly an inspired answer, and if you have a vision, please feel free.